# Unity project merge problem: Scene cannot load prefabs correctly

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

My unity scene cannot load prefabs correctly after merge. I checked prefabs and they look good. I have two versions of my project A and B which have conflicts in scene.unity. I tried to resolve conflicts by replacing scene.unity with the one in version B. But unity keeps loading scene from A. And I auto-merged conflicts in some binary files. Does the problem lie in those binary files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *`I auto-merged conflicts in some binary files`* Yeah, that was a mistake.

Comment: Is there a way to solve it? I cannot even open these binary files.

Comment: You can't merge binary files. No ifs-ands-or-buts about it. This isn't a Git thing, its a binary file thing. Binary formats simply can't be modified in a way that allows source control to do anything other than "its a file, its changed." By merging two versions together you created garbage. For example, storing an array of integers involves saving the *length* and then *each integer.* What happens if the length changes, but not the number of items? What about the reverse?

Comment: is there a way to solve? First you should go back to the latest commit before the merge. Then when the conflicts happen again rather chose e.g. use [`--theirs or --ours`](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts/) in order to completely override binaries. In general for binary data rather use [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/)